# Integral of Chebyshev polynomial expression $\int_{0}^{1} x^{-1/3}\cos(3\arccos(x))dx$

Tags: integration, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to integrate

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-1/3}\cos(3\arccos(x))dx$$

but I am getting nowhere. The usual $$x=\cos(\theta)$$ substitution and other similar ones I have tried do not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: Note that $$\cos 3\theta \,  = \, 4 \cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta $$

Use this with $\theta = \arccos(x)$. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For each real $ X,$ we have

$$\cos(3X) = 4\cos^3(X)-3\cos(X)$$

and for each $ Y\in [-1,1] $

$$\cos(\arccos(Y))=Y$$

The  improper integral becomes

$$\int_0^1x^{-\frac 13}(4x^3-3x)dx=$$
$$4.\frac{3}{11}-3.\frac 35=\frac{-39}{55}$$

Comment: Domain of arccos is only $[-1,1]$, not all reals.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes of course, thanks a lot.